# Systemd - daemonizing celery - Failed at step CHDIR spawning /bin/sh: No such file or directory

Tags: celery, centos7, systemd

This is basically the same service file that the [celery docs](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/daemonizing.html) tells you to use as a basic beginners file.

With the below configuration, journalctl -ex displays the error "Failed at step CHDIR spawning /bin/sh: No such file or directory".

**/etc/systemd/system/celery.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=apache
Group=apache
#Environment=PATH=/opt/python39/lib:/home/ec2-user/DjangoProjects/myproj
#Environment=PATH=/home/ec2-user/DjangoProjects/myproj
EnvironmentFile=/etc/conf.d/celery
#WorkingDirectory=/opt/python39
WorkingDirectory=/home/ec2-usuer/DjangoProjects/myproj
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} -A $CELERY_APP multi start $CELERYD_NODES \
    --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} \
    --loglevel="${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL}" $CELERYD_OPTS'
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait $CELERYD_NODES \
    --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} \
    --loglevel="${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL}"'
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} -A $CELERY_APP multi restart $CELERYD_NODES \
    --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} \
    --loglevel="${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL}" $CELERYD_OPTS'
Restart=always


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**/etc/conf.d/celery**

```
# Name of nodes to start
# here we have a single node
#CELERYD_NODES="w1"
# or we could have three nodes:
CELERYD_NODES="w1 w2 w3"

# Absolute or relative path to the 'celery' command:
#CELERY_BIN="/home/ec2-user/.local/bin/celery"
CELERY_BIN="/opt/python39/bin/celery"
#CELERY_BIN="/virtualenvs/def/bin/celery"

CELERYD_CHDIR="/home/ec2-user/DjangoProjects/myproj"

# App instance to use
# comment out this line if you don't use an app
#CELERY_APP="myproj"
CELERY_APP="myproj.celery_tasks"
#CELERY_APP="myproj.celery_tasks:myapp"
# ^^ ??? confusion ??? ^^
# or fully qualified:
#CELERY_APP="proj.tasks:app"

# How to call manage.py
CELERYD_MULTI="multi"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"

# - %n will be replaced with the first part of the nodename.
# - %I will be replaced with the current child process index
#   and is important when using the prefork pool to avoid race conditions.
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"

# you may wish to add these options for Celery Beat
CELERYBEAT_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/beat.pid"
CELERYBEAT_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/beat.log"

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="myproj.settings"
```

If I leave out the WorkingDirectory in the service file, it throws this error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproj'".

I've spent the last 2 days looking at different configurations and what not, and I haven't been able to get past one of these 2 errors. What am I missing?

Comment: From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Rob nice to know. I was asking myself which exchange to use, and thought in the end it probably didn't matter too much. I've seen a bunch of related questions on SO.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve it!

I found [this link](https://seulcode.tistory.com/440) that was a tutorial... which said that WorkingDirectory and CELERYD_CHDIR are the same.

I also read something on SO that suggested using a virtual environment... so I did that, too :).

The updated files:

**/etc/systemd/system/celery.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=apache
Group=apache
#Environment=PATH=/opt/python39/lib:/home/ec2-user/DjangoProjects/myproj
#Environment=PATH=/home/ec2-user/DjangoProjects/myproj
EnvironmentFile=/etc/conf.d/celery
#WorkingDirectory=/opt/python39
WorkingDirectory=/home/ec2-user/DjangoProjects/myproj
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} -A $CELERY_APP multi start $CELERYD_NODES \
    --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} \
    --loglevel="${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL}" $CELERYD_OPTS'
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait $CELERYD_NODES \
    --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} \
    --loglevel="${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL}"'
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} -A $CELERY_APP multi restart $CELERYD_NODES \
    --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} \
    --loglevel="${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL}" $CELERYD_OPTS'
Restart=always


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**/etc/conf.d/celery**

```
# Name of nodes to start
# here we have a single node
#CELERYD_NODES="w1"
# or we could have three nodes:
CELERYD_NODES="w1 w2 w3"

# Absolute or relative path to the 'celery' command:
#CELERY_BIN="/home/ec2-user/.local/bin/celery"
#CELERY_BIN="/opt/python39/bin/celery"
CELERY_BIN="/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/myproj_prod/bin/celery"
#CELERY_BIN="/virtualenvs/def/bin/celery"

CELERYD_CHDIR="/home/ec2-user/DjangoProjects/myproj"

# App instance to use
# comment out this line if you don't use an app
#CELERY_APP="myproj"
#CELERY_APP="myproj.celery_tasks"
CELERY_APP="myproj.celery_tasks"
#CELERY_APP="myproj.celery_tasks:myapp"
# ^^ ??? confusion ??? ^^
# or fully qualified:
#CELERY_APP="proj.tasks:app"

# How to call manage.py
CELERYD_MULTI="multi"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"

# - %n will be replaced with the first part of the nodename.
# - %I will be replaced with the current child process index
#   and is important when using the prefork pool to avoid race conditions.
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"

# you may wish to add these options for Celery Beat
CELERYBEAT_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/beat.pid"
CELERYBEAT_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/beat.log"

DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="myproj.settings"
```

After I created `/var/run/celery/` and `/var/log/celery/` folders, I ran chmod and gave access to the user and group that would be running the service to those folders - apache.